# Request.Get in url.py in django

Tags: django

I'm fairly new to Django and have used the tutorial videos of Sir Sentdex in youtube.

I'm trying to integrate a search function in his example but I think he used a different approach in making his example. He didn't use the app's (Product) views.py but instead went straight to url.py

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Product.objects.all(), template_name="product/product.html"))]
```

I made a form with search in my *header.html* and then extends it in *product.html* .

Here is the code of the form with search:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method='GET' action=''>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="searchfield form-control" id="searchproduct" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
<input type='submit' value='Search'>
</div>
</form>
```

How can I make the url pattern in the app's url.py like:

```
query = request.GET.get('q') <- I know this should be in a function.

urlpatterns = [ url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Product.objects.filter(
Q(name__contains=query  | desc__contains=query )
), template_name="product/product.html"))]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're starting to diverge away from any advantages of defining the whole view in the url, separate it into a view

Comment: HI @Sayse. So you are saying that the tutorials of Sir Sentdex are wrong, I mean using his way is causing more disadvantages than advantages?

Comment: No, the way they used it seems perfectly fine since there wasn't a lot to define. You however - do have a lot to define

Comment: So Sirs, There's no way I can make the request.GET in the url.py happen?

Comment: OP, no therere isn't since you'd need to do this inside the `get_queryset` method

Comment: @Sayse Thanks man. Your help is much appreciated.